# X-editable manual submit form

Tags: jquery, ajax, onchange, x-editable

I need an advice to manual submit `x-editable`.

I have a form with title text input and input with `x-editable` - `identifier`.

So if I write a new record, I need change identifier after title change.

On change function works, but none of these possible options not work.

```
    $("#title").change(function() {
        console.log('test');
        $('#identifier').editable().submit();
        $('#identifier').editable('submit');
        $('#identifier .editable').editable('submit');
        //$('#identifier').editable('submit');
    });
```

Thank you for advice!

---

EDIT: problem solved by using standart jQuery AJAX

Thank you all!

Comment: The `.editable('submit');` version should work. But the behaviour seems strange, why would you change an input (#identifier) when it does not change at all (only the title changing) ?

Comment: Because it is editable field `<a href="#" id="identifier" class="editable editable-click" style="display: inline;">identifier</a>` - `$('#identifier').editable({...})`

Comment: Are you sure it is 'submit' you are looking for ? From what I understand : User lands on your page and he changes the title. X-editable will submit automatically the title, good. But now why would it submit identifier ? The value didn't change at all, there is nothing to update ! I think that you are looking for a way for #identifier to "pop-up" `$('#identifier').editable('show');`

Comment: I know it is a little bit confusing, but here is explanation: User go to page and change title. Now - identifier must coresponds with this title, but I must call ajax method in editable because identifier is generated by php and database. If this cannot be done with x-editable, I use standart ajax call and sets data to x-editable.

Comment: Oh I see, this has nothing to do with submit because what you want would be rather "update". But it doesn't exist in X-Editable, you need to $.ajax() with jQuery, get the new value(s), and use the method `$("#identifier").editable("setValue",my_new_value);`